# enviar formulario por mail php

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario `html` el cual quiero que se me envíe por `mail` cuando se le da al botón enviar, cuando relleno el formulario y le doy a enviar, no me llega el `mail`, pero me pasa todas las validaciones y me salta que se ha enviado el `mail` correctamente. Sí no se ha rellenado ningún campo o hay datos que no son correctos, como por ej. el campo `mail`, me salta el error.

He buscado por internet y he visto por aquí preguntas similares, pero cuando veo la solución (recoger datos del formulario crear los `headers`, el asunto, el cuerpo y el `mail to`), creo que están iguales, pero no me envía el `mail`.

**HTML**

```
<form action="enviar_email.php" method="post">

            <label for="first_name">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" size=36 name="first_name">
            <label for="last_name">Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" size=36 name="last_name">
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" size=36 name="email">
            <label for="telephone">Teléfono</label>
            <input type="tel" size=36 name="telephone">
            <label for="message">Mensaje</label>
            <textarea rows=5 cols=30 name="message"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="reset" value="Borrar">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

        </form>
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
     // Edita las líneas siguientes con tu dirección de correo y asunto
     $email_to = "micorreo@dominio.com"; //el mail al que quiero que me llegue el formulario

        $email_subject = "I want a be an instructor";   

        function died($error) {

        // si hay algún error, el formulario puede desplegar su mensaje de aviso

        echo "Lo sentimos, hay un error en sus datos y el formulario no puede ser enviado. ";

        echo "Detalle de los errores.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Por favor corrije los errores e inténtelo de nuevo.<br /><br />";
            die();
        }

        // Se valida que los campos del formulairo estén llenos

        if(empty($_POST['first_name']) ||
            empty($_POST['last_name']) ||
            empty($_POST['email']) ||
            empty($_POST['telephone']) ||
            empty($_POST['message'])) {

            died('Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.');       

        }
     //Valor "name" nos sirve para crear las variables que recolectaran la información de cada campo

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // requerido
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // requerido
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // requerido
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // no requerido 
        $message = $_POST['message']; // requerido
        $error_message = "Error";

    //Verificar que la dirección de correo sea válida 

       $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

      if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {     
  $error_message .= 'La dirección de correo proporcionada no es válida.<br />';     
      }

    //Validadacion de cadenas de texto

        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

      if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {     
        $error_message .= 'El formato del nombre no es válido<br />';     
      }

      if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {     
        $error_message .= 'el formato del apellido no es válido.<br />';     
      }

      if(strlen($message) < 2) {     
        $error_message .= 'El formato del texto no es válido.<br />';     
      }

      if(strlen($error_message) < 0) {     
        died($error_message);     
      }

    //Plantilla de mensaje

        $email_message = "Contenido del Mensaje.\n\n";

        function clean_string($string) {     
          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");     
          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);     
        }

        $email_message .= "Nombre: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";     
        $email_message .= "Apellido: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";     
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";     
        $email_message .= "Teléfono: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";     
        $email_message .= "Mensaje: ".clean_string($message)."\n";      

    //Encabezados

    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . $email_from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email_from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

    ?>

    <!-- Mensaje de Éxito-->

    Muchas Gracias! Proximamente Estaremos en Contacto.

    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar? porque no encuentro el error

Muchas gracias

Comment: Intenta poner una variable el metodo maíl para saber sí da algún error, así `$success = mail(....)`

Comment: prueba a quitar la @ en `@mail(...` porque eso te oculta los errores de la funcion; asignalo a una variable y mira si tiene el valor 0. Recuerda que segun la documentacion oficial de mail https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php el hecho de ser aceptado para enviar, no significa que llegue al destino. Tambien te recomendaria que no uses  "\r\n" sino `PHP_EOL`

Comment: he quitado la @ en el `@mail(...)` y nada, la he intentado poner en una variable como me comentaba @DaxTter77 y tampoco me funciona, me sigue dando que se envió correctamente pero no me da ningún error por consola ni me llega el mail

Comment: imprime la variable, aquí te paso una referencia que encontré http://www.rephp.com/captura-de-errores-de-php-mail-y-muestra-un-mensaje-de-error-razonable-del-usuario.html  ahí para saber exactamente cual es el error que te da

Comment: pues sinceramente no sé que pasa, seguiré intentando a ver si lo averiguo, intento imprimir la variable como me pone en el enlace que me has pasado y no me va o me da **error 500** de por haberla implementado mal.

Comment: Sí logras hacer mostrar el error con ese método lo agregas a la pregunta para así poder ayudar a resolverlo

Comment: Si eres capaz de confirmar que el correo sale, no olvides revisar la carpeta de correo no deseado.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero de todo mira el config si tienes habilitado para enviar emails.
Si tienes el XAMPP normalmente, por defecto viene activo.

[configurar config.php para email](https://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm)

Comment: la configuración del php.ini hay que configurarlo siempre o sólo si se está trabajando en localhost? ya que esto está subido ya al servidor y no trabajo en local

Comment: Hay que configurarlo siempre, otra opcion es usar algun framework como phpmailer 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: lo de que asignes el valor a una variable, tipo `$enviado = mail(...` es para que nos digas que valor te da `$enviado`. un true seria que se ha `ACEPTADO` para enviar, y un  false que ha habido problemas. En cualquier caso, con `mail` no puedes asegurar que el correo llegue al destino (lo pone en la documentacion oficial). Como te dice @Srsole prueba sino con alguna libreria de envio como PHPMailer o `SwiftMailer` (yo te recomendaria esta ultima)`

Comment: hola Jakala, nunca he escuchado 'SwiftMailer', por que la recomiendas? por que la conoces mejor? o por algun aspecto tecnico? Estaria bien saberlo, por que yo  lo uso bastante y siempre va bien estar informado. Gracias! ;)

Answer (score 0):

A mi me pasaba lo mismo en algunos formularios, cuando hacia pruebas con gmail o hotmail, hasta que descubrí que el remitente del correo debe ser un mail del dominio en el que se encuentra el formulario (créalo).  Prueba con

```
'$email_from = contacto@tudominio.com'; // requerido'.
```

y en Reply-To si lo puedes dejar como esta para que le contestes a la persona que realiza el contacto.   Espero te sirva.

Derek, esto pasa porque no estas enviando el correo desde los servidores que alojan el correo del remitente (gmail, hotmail, outlook) es una suplantación.  Por esto te sugiero que crees un correo contacto@midominio.com y es desde el que "te envíes el correo", igual en el cuerpo del mensaje y en el Reply-to tienes el correo que han puesto en el formulario y al dar clic en contestar le contestas al correo puesto en el formulario y también evita que no lleguen por ser inexistentes al ser digitados mal como @gmail.cm o @hotmail.co. Esto esta dentro de los filtros antispam y de protección de suplantación de identidad de la mayoría de servidores.

Comment: no entiendo lo que me quieres decir, en sí el `$email_from` es el mail que introduce la persona en el formulario y me tendría que llegar a mi mail, es decir, `$email_to` y no sé por qué no me llega

Comment: es tomado como una suplantación de identidad